# Large JavaScript file bundling generate incomplete result JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, client-side, bundling-and-minification

we use a third party JavaScript  library witch written in a file with more than
130000 line
after bundling process and Minification 
in client side codes some feature are missing
any idea why it's happening?

Comment: Any further info? Link to file? Does it truncate it or?

Comment: the file is 3.70 Mb we also have a min  version of that file
is there anyway to use minified version in build process automatically?

Comment: That's a large JavaScript file. What does it do? I don't even consider adding a such large file to my documents. I hope you don't use the file because you just need some of it's features.

Comment: it's OpenLayers Map Library